# MYSQL access denied for 'user'@'ip'

Tags: mysql, cpanel

am on my cpanel and i have already created my database and linked it to my user, created a simple code to test the connection

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

but on running it gives me this error

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'ip' (using password: YES)
```

tried searching for solutions online but none have been helpful, am stuck and any help will be highly appreciated
thanks in advance.

and i know this question has been asked before but that was for a local database so the answer won't really sort me out

Comment: Please share your cpanel details.Let me check it

Comment: ^^ haha no need for that xD have you tried logging in to mysql server from command line with the output of $username and $password? Do they work?

Comment: @HaninderSingh you know i cant do that

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs cpanel is online, how do i do that with cmd

Comment: @lulliezy use your cpanel details to ssh in? is ssh enabled?

Comment: how do i do that since there is no option to even add the ssh in my cpanel @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Comment: what no way :o ok well nvm, you can ask the host to set up and hopefully you can then ssh in (will be `ssh username@serverip`) then `mysql -uusername -p` then when it prompts for password, enter it - if error occurs you may have wrong mysql deets

Comment: i found a fix, created another database through database wizard, and it worked, i don't know how though but still am looking for the solution of the ssh problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the necessary privilegies are granted for the account. Note, the accounts with the same user name have **different permissions when** connected from **different hosts**. See [Adding User Accounts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html) article for details. Use the `'%'` wildcard for the host part of account name, to allow user connects from any host to your MySQL server with same privilegies.

Comment: tried adding the permissions via phpmyadmin sql box but still access denied, i mean i cant change anything because no access